# How to put a HTML tag to another HTML tag with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to put a **`<div id="all_content">`** element into **`<sector id="all_field">`** element with Javascript

```
<section id="all_field"></section>
<div id="all_content">
    <h1>---&nbsp;&nbsp;Meeting Room Booking&nbsp;&nbsp;---</h1>
    <fieldset class="box"><legend class="booking_meetRom">Approved Status of Meeting</legend>
        <div><a>More Detail</a> </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="box"><legend class="booking_meetRom">123</legend>
        <div>123</div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Here is **JSFIDDLE**: **http://jsfiddle.net/Y6MpQ/**

It should be like this:

```
<section id="all_field">
<div id="all_content">
    <h1>---&nbsp;&nbsp;Meeting Room Booking&nbsp;&nbsp;---</h1>
    <fieldset class="box">
        <legend class="booking_meetRom">Approved Status of Meeting</legend>
        <div><a>More Detail</a> </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="box">
        <legend class="booking_meetRom">123</legend>
        <div>123</div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
</section>
```

**JSFIDDLE should be**: **http://jsfiddle.net/Y6MpQ/1/**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `.append()` in this context,

```
$('#all_field').append($('#all_content'));
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6MpQ/2/)

Comment: That's great :-) Thank you very much. Do you think that `<section>` element will work with IE 8? If not, is there any others element for changing?

Comment: @PMay1903 No.. its a kind of html5 tag. only ie >= 9 will support html 5.

Comment: @PMay1903 `<div>` should be a great alternative for `<section>` like tags.

Comment: It's awesome. I have changed `<section>` to `<div>` and it worked as before with IE=8. Thanks again :-).

Answer (score 2):

With Jquery you can use append

```
$html = '<div id="all_content">';
$html += '<h1>---&nbsp;&nbsp;Meeting Room Booking&nbsp;&nbsp;---</h1>';
$html += '<fieldset class="box">';
$html += '<legend class="booking_meetRom">Approved Status of Meeting</legend>';
$html += '<div><a>More Detail</a> </div>';
$html += '</fieldset>';
$html += '<fieldset class="box">';
$html += '<legend class="booking_meetRom">123</legend>';
$html += '<div>123</div>';
$html += '</fieldset>';
$html += '</div>';

$('#all_content').append($html);
```

Comment: This will throw error. proper concatenation should be applied.

Comment: why would you use the dollar sign for variable declaration?

Comment: That is OK. Thank you for your code but there is something that needs you to change :-)

Answer (score 2):

Using pure JavaScript:

```
var field = document.getElementById('all_field');
var content = document.getElementById('all_content');

field.innerHTML = content.outerHTML;
content.remove();
```

See the working code at:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EaKWw/4/)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This might work well. However, Do you think that it might not be optimized as minimum as **Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy**'s method?

Comment: This is a pure JS solution, no JQuery is needed. For some folks, this is considered the bare minimum solution :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#all_content").prependTo("#all_field")
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/sjMqL/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`document.getElementById("all_field").innerHTML = "<div id="all_content">";`

or JQuery:

`$("#all_field").html("<div id="all_content">");`